# Is it possible to prevent a string from being printed in lua

Tags: lua, obfuscation

So I am working on a lua obfuscator and it is going pretty good but i've noticed that if you go to the end of the script and just change loadstring to print you get the whole script, how would I fix this?

Here is a Hello World project obfuscated:

```
--Protected by blueSecure(1.2)

getgenv().ProtectedByBlueSecure = true
local b='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/' function dec(data) data = string.gsub(data, '[^'..b..'=]', '') return (data:gsub('.', function(x) if (x == '=') then return '' end local r,f='',(b:find(x)-1) for i=6,1,-1 do r=r..(f%2^i-f%2^(i-1)>0 and '1' or '0') end return r; end):gsub('%d%d%d?%d?%d?%d?%d?%d?', function(x) if (#x ~= 8) then return '' end local c=0 for i=1,8 do c=c+(x:sub(i,i)=='1' and 2^(8-i) or 0) end return string.char(c) end))end
return(function(...)
(({...})[1])[1]=(({...})[2])()[dec('Z2FtZQ=="')]; 

(({...})[1])[1]=dec('aWY=');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mg=='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MQ=='))] .. dec('IA==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mw=='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mg=='))] .. dec('Z2V0Z2Vudg==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('NA=='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mw=='))] .. dec('KCku');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('NQ=='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('NA=='))] .. dec('UHJvdGVjdGVkQnlCbHVlU2VjdXJl');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Ng=='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('NQ=='))] .. dec('IA==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Nw=='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Ng=='))] .. dec('dGhlbg==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('OA=='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Nw=='))] .. dec('IA==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('OQ=='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('OA=='))] .. dec('cHJpbnQ=');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTA='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('OQ=='))] .. dec('KCI=');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTE='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTA='))] .. dec('SGVsbG8=');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTI='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTE='))] .. dec('IA==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTM='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTI='))] .. dec('V29ybGQ=');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTQ='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTM='))] .. dec('ISIpIA==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTU='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTQ='))] .. dec('ZWxzZQ==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTY='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTU='))] .. dec('CiAgICA=');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTc='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTY='))] .. dec('Z2FtZQ==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTg='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTc='))] .. dec('Og==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTk='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTg='))] .. dec('R2V0U2VydmljZQ==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MjA='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MTk='))] .. dec('KCI=');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MjE='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MjA='))] .. dec('UGxheWVycw==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MjI='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MjE='))] .. dec('Iiku');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MjM='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MjI='))] .. dec('TG9jYWxQbGF5ZXI=');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MjQ='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MjM='))] .. dec('Og==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MjU='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MjQ='))] .. dec('S2ljaw==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MjY='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MjU='))] .. dec('KCI=');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mjc='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MjY='))] .. dec('U3RvcA==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mjg='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mjc='))] .. dec('IA==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mjk='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mjg='))] .. dec('cmVtb3Zpbmc=');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MzA='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mjk='))] .. dec('IA==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MzE='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MzA='))] .. dec('Y3JlZGl0cw==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MzI='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MzE='))] .. dec('IA==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MzM='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MzI='))] .. dec('eW91');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MzQ='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MzM='))] .. dec('IA==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MzU='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MzQ='))] .. dec('dGhpZWY=');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MzY='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MzU='))] .. dec('LCA=');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mzc='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('MzY='))] .. dec('Ymx1ZVNlY3VyZQ==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mzg='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mzc='))] .. dec('IikKIA==');
(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mzk='))]=(({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mzg='))] .. dec('ZW5k');loadstring((({...})[1])[tonumber(dec('Mzk='))])()end)({},getfenv,table.remove)
```

And please do not point out that I am using Base64, will change this once I have gotten everything working

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Yes and no. Yes because you could delete all the printing functions (such as `print`, `io.write`, `error`) at the start of your code. But then you couldn't ever use those functions.

No because the person trying to read your code could just delete the code that deletes the functions, then use them. Whatever code you add to try and prevent printing, they can just delete it, then print.

You may find it useful to compile your program to *Lua bytecode*, and then obfuscate the bytecode and load the bytecode. Bytecode is more difficult to read than source code. You could also try to rename all the functions and variables in the code into random strings. I didn't bother to decode your code to see whether it has random function and variable names, but since you are trying to obfuscate it this way, I am *guessing* that you didn't.

By the way, making the code look confusing doesn't add anything. It is *really easy* to change `function(...)` to `function(t, getfenv, table_remove)` and then just find-and-replace `({...})[1]` with `t` for example. In this case you may as well just write it the easy way to begin with because this is not going to slow down an attacker at all.

Comment: And i like to comment that just for hiding you can use the power of metatables. For this i have a ```__index``` in mind. With that power you can design a table that behave is totally strange when examined. For example the method ```__tostring``` can not only return a string it also can execute ```os.exit()``` before. The ```__metatable``` method is a good place for "Fake News" about a metatable itself. By the way, what Lua Version i have to compile for: ```loadstring()``` ?

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi `loadstring` was deprecated in Lua 5.2. Its functionality was merged into `load`

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi it doesn't matter. the attacker can just DELETE all your fancy metatable code.

Comment: ```if``` the attacker deletes the associated metatable ```then``` all functions/tables/whatever stored in ```__index``` are also destroyed (at next garbagecolletor cycle)

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi they won't delete the metatable. They'll delete the *code*. Remember they can see all your obfuscated code and change it. If you have a section of code that makes it impossible to print certain strings, they can just delete that section, and then run the rest